# Filter by list of ids in RethinkDB java

Tags: java, rethinkdb

am using RethinkDB with java driver and i want to get rows by list of id's

until now i used :

```
.filter(row -> row.g("_id").eq("one")
```

but if i want to search where _id is equal to ["one","two", ...] (list of items)

iv seen an examples on how to do it in javascript and found this :-

```
    r.db("test2").table("table2").filter(
  function (doc) {
    return r.expr(["two","one"])
            .contains(doc("_id"))
  }
)
```

any idea how to do it with java driver

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
r.table("users").filter(
    user -> r.expr(r.array("two", "one")).contains(user.g("_id"))
).run(conn);
```

The [rethinkdb documentation](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/java/filter/) has more examples that might help.